# how to use httpclient processor in Spring cloud Dataflow

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying out spring cloud dataflow. My specific usecase is to dump the response from a GET request to a log. I am trying to use the httpclient processor for this. But i dont understand how come it is a processor, and not a source. If it a processor, what should be the input source to it. Any example would do great.

Comment: Can you post your code please ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires an incoming Message to trigger the http request.  The message may specify the URL, HTTP Method, etc. using SpEL expressions but these may also be statically configured as well.  For example, you can use the time source to trigger a request every second.